# How to use e as base for log-axis labels?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels, axis

I am using pgfplots with `semilogyaxis`. When I use `log base y={e}` the tick label numbers of my y-axis are displayed with base 10 in agreement with chapter 4.15.4 of the pgfplots manual (Revision 1.14, 2016-08-10). 
I want to change the base of the displayed numbers to e. Is there a simple way with the `log base` option?

MWE:

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{semilogyaxis}[
     log base y={e}]
     \addplot [domain=1:5] {e^x}; 
 \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make your code a compilable document instead of a fragment. It makes it a lot easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the manual the *shown* log basis is 10 when the *used* log basis is e. To overcome this issue we simply provide the number of e to `log basis y` and replace the default `#1` of `log number format basis` to `e`.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        log basis ticks=y,
        log basis y={2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995},
        log number format basis/.code 2 args={
            $e^{\pgfmathprintnumber{#2}}$
        },
    ]
        \addplot [domain=1:5] {e^x};
    \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]